# Tilemill error Could not create datasource for type: 'postgis' (searched for datasource plugins in '/usr/lib/mapnik/input')

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapnik

Followed link [OSM Quick start](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/)

Had little bilt problems but i managed to perform all the steps. But when my opened my newly created project in tilemill we just mad it shows error

> Could not create datasource for type: 'postgis' (searched for datasource plugins in '/usr/lib/mapnik/input')  encountered during parsing of layer 'landuse_gen0' in Layer at line 197

Can somebody tell me what this error and how to resolve it. I have followed all steps n provide link above?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34959/tilemill-error-could-not-create-datasource-for-type-postgis-searched-for-datasource-plugins-in-usrlibmapnikinput

Comment: Did you install TileMill from source?

Comment: The problem was due to  mapnik-input-plugin-postgis

Answer (score 1):

The "[OSM Bright Quick Start](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/)" page is a bit outdated. A few differences to handle installing postgres/postgis for Linux Mint 17.1/Ubuntu 14.04 to handle in Step 0 + 1:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
sudo apt-get install mapnik-input-plugin-postgis
# Set every method to "trust"
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
psql -U postgres -c "create database osm;"
psql -U postgres -d osm -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -U postgres -d osm -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

This worked for me. Then follow with Step 2...

Answer (score 0):

You should check the directory `/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input`, and you will find the file `postgis.input` is missing.

The reason is that when you compile mapnik, the dependency for plugin 'postgis' can not be satisfied. You can run `python scons/scons.py INPUT_PLUGINS='postgis'` in the shell and you would be reminded some dependency problem. So you should add the postgresql and postgis to the system environment before make mapnik.

Make sure postgresql94-devel has been already installed or you can run `sudo yum install postgresql94-devel`.Then, you can do like this

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.4/lib:/usr/local/lib`

and then use the `./configure`,`make` and `make install` command for mapnik. After reinstallation of mapnik, you should find `postgis.input` in the directory `/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input` and then try again.